# Problem proccessing checkbox on MAMP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have two separately named checkboxes sending values to the following script.
I seem completely unable to reliably tell if the checkboxes are on or off.

I have checked the values are being sent in the $_POST and they are as expected.
Please help!

```
$form = $_POST['form'];
$recruit = $_POST['recruiting'];


if (empty ($form)) {
    $form = "0";
} else {
    $form = "1";
}

if ($recruit) {
    $recruit = "0";
} else {
    $recruit = "1";
}
```

Comment: Multiple checkboxes need to be in array notation in the HTML. Do you have this? For example, `mycheckbox[]`

Comment: use var_dump($_POST) to understand what data you are receiving and how you should handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isset():

```
$form = isset($_POST['form']) ? true : false;
```

Comment: It mostly depends on the value attribute of your checkbox. If the value is "" or "0" then the sent value will be false. `empty($var)` is basically the same as `isset($var) && $var`. But when checking if a checkbox is checked, you don't want to check the value. You want to check if the key is set. If a checkbox is not checked, the key on `$_POST` will not be set. Hope that clears it up.